# Java - How to perform operations on a value in an array?

Tags: java

This is the operation i am trying to do. I get the error "bad operand types for binary operator "*".

How do i pass this calcualtion? Can somone show me an example of how to do this? Note that day[i] has all its values already in it.

Comment: something funny about syntax. Temperature is a function?

Comment: What is day? i see only dayF

Comment: What is the type of `day`?

Comment: @Coffee there is nothing funny about the syntax... i believe its called constructor to a class with a parameter.

Comment: Can you post your `Temperature` constructor?

Comment: I have posted the constructor

Comment: is `day[i]` an `int`?

Comment: it's wrong ! should be this.temp = temp

Comment: For the constructor you almost certainly want it in the other order: `this.temp = temp`. As is you're changing the value of the local variable, which is promptly deleted

Comment: `temp = this.temp;` is completely wrong. It should be `this.temp = temp;`

Comment: You seem to have deleted all the code from the question! You need to roll this edit back (click on the "edited 1 hour ago" link), because the question now makes no sense, and is highly likely to get deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complaint is that `day[i]*9` doesn't make any sense. This must be because `day[i]` isn't a numerical type.

If `day` is also of type `Temperature[]`, then you can't multiply `day[i]` by anything because it's an object, not a number. You'll need to write a method of `Temperature` that allows you to read the value stored there:

```
public class Temperature {

    private double temp;

    // constructors etc.

    public double getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Now you can use

```
(day[i].getTemp()*9)/5+32
```

to get what you want. Note that I've set the type as `double`, because it looks like you'll want floating point arithmetic here.

Comment: So now can i do the follwing? dayF[i] = new Temperature((day[i].getValue()*9)/5+32);

Comment: @Darius Yes, but (1) I changed the name from `getValue()` to `getTemp()` to fit with the name of `temp`; (2) you should change the type of `temp` to `double`, including in the parameter to your constructor.